# Set last clicked checkbox element as checked on form submit

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a form where user can choose between 4 options.

```
<ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="mediaChannelFilter" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="test" value="1" {{ (Request::get('mediaChannelFilter')==1) ? "checked":"" }}>&nbsp;Option 1</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="mediaChannelFilter" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="test" value="2" {{ (Request::get('mediaChannelFilter')==2) ? "checked":"" }}>&nbsp;Option 2</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="mediaChannelFilter" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="test" value="3" {{ (Request::get('mediaChannelFilter')==3) ? "checked":"" }}>&nbsp;Option 3</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="mediaChannelFilter" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="test" value="4" {{ (Request::get('mediaChannelFilter')==4) ? "checked":"" }}>&nbsp;Option 4</li>
 </ul>
```

And it works fine when I select first option, then second, then third and fourth. `{{ (Request::get('mediaChannelFilter')}}` works fine and makes last clicked element as checked. But problem occurs when I click last option first and then I want to click previous one.

In URL I get:

```
http://myapp.com?mediaChannelFilter=1&mediaChannelFilter=4
```

And Option four stays checked. How can I make it unchecked and set, for example, Option two as checked.

Now it turns just into this:

```
http://myapp.com?mediaChannelFilter=2&mediaChannelFilter=4
```

Comment: when you check first and last checkbox is automatically embed in url ?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to select more than one of those options at a time? If not, you should be using radio buttons instead of checkboxes to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Is it possible to be able to select more than one of options because I have `onchange="this.form.submit()"`? And I cannot uncheck radio button, that's why I don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

### Radios

I think you need [radios](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio) because then it could be only one option that will be `checked`.
Through that you get the url like that
`http://myapp.com?mediaChannelFilter=4`

### Checkboxes

Otherwise if you want to permit many values because many checkboxes are `checked` than you can change the parameter `name` into this `name="mediaChannelFilter[]"`
Through that you get the url like that
`http://myapp.com?mediaChannelFilter[]=1&mediaChannelFilter[]=4`

### jQuery

You can solve it like this too

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.test').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="mediaChannelFilter" class="test" value="1" />&nbsp;Option 1</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="mediaChannelFilter" class="test" value="2" />&nbsp;Option 2</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="mediaChannelFilter" class="test" value="3" />&nbsp;Option 3</li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" name="mediaChannelFilter" class="test" value="4" />&nbsp;Option 4</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Like I've said. I don't use radios since they cannot be unchecked. And when I use name arrays `mediaChannelFilter[]`I get the error - `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`